# Drupal Rules Scheduler sends out duplicate emails (Drupal 7 Views-Rules integration)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am sending out a nightly email through rules scheduler, when I manually execute it sends out one email as it should, however when it runs on the schedule it sends me 10 duplicate emails. I've looked all over and can't seem to find any solution to the problem.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Use Job scheduler module. In this module you first insert the data in job_schedule and create a queue for each schedule . when crons run it start executing each queue and send mails then it delete its entry from the job_scheduler table. hence it will not send same mail again and again to the same person.. There is proper documentation in job_scheduler module in drupal7. Just go through it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the Rules module; it has its quirks. I see you have reported this issue in the Rules issue queue: http://drupal.org/node/1314916, which is what I was first going to suggest. So now I know your issue is for Rules 7.x-2.x dev integration with Views 7... both of which have more than a few bugs. I strongly suspect this issue has as much to do with Views as with Rules. (The 10x repetition seems unlikely to be a coincidence since 10 is a default value for results-per-page in Views, etc)

When you report an issue, it's helpful to include all pertinent information (Drupal version, steps to replicate, what's written to the log, etc). I'd personally suggest seeing if you can replicate your issue in a clean installation of Drupal with just the modules necessary to run your test. If you can replicate it that way, it's easier to provide enough information for the developers to identify the issue and resolve it. (e.g. use Devel generate to create some nodes and dummy users, then create a very simple view, e.g. just titles of the five most recent nodes, and use that view as the source for your email content. Does it send 5 copies? You may need to configure a localhost mail server to test this.

Comment: Thanks for your response! After a bit of just deleting the duplicates from the schedule, it managed to work itself out.